# How do I swap elements of rows of a Nx2 numpy array if a condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, numpy, swap, idioms

I'd like to swap elements of the i-th row a Nx2 numpy array `my_array` if a condition `swap[i]` is `True`.

My attempt:

```
def swap_positions_conditionally(my_array, swap):
    for i in range(np.shape(my_array)[0]):
        if swap[i]:
            my_array[i] = my_array[i][::-1]
    return my_array
```

works fine, e.g. given

```
my_array = array([[0, 1],
                  [2, 3],
                  [4, 5],
                  [6, 7],
                  [8, 9]])

swap = array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

yields the expected result

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [5 4]
 [7 6]
 [8 9]]
```

However, there's likely a more idiomatic expression to rewrite my `swap_position_conditionally`.
What would be a better (and more efficient) way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's one using Numpy's boolean indexing directly:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.asarray([[0, 1],
                  [2, 3],
                  [4, 5],
                  [6, 7],
                  [8, 9]])

swap = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=bool)

my_array[swap, :] = my_array[swap,:][:,(1,0)]
```

Breaking down the key line:

- `my_array[swap, :] =` means "Assign to the rows where `swap` is true"
- `my_array[swap,:]` means "select the whole row where `swap` is true"
- `[:,(1,0)]` means "for each row of what's to the left, swap the columns 0 and 1"

### About the "more efficient" part of the question...

Common setup for all tests (seed ensures sequences are identical):

```
import timeit
setup= '''
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
my_array = np.random.random([10000,2])
swap = np.random.random([10000]) > 0.5
'''
```

All tests run for 1000 iterations

#### Original code: 5.621 seconds

```
timeit.timeit('swap_positions_conditionally(my_array, swap)', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

Added the definition of `swap_positions_conditionally` to `setup` as shown in the question.

#### This answer: 0.2657 seconds

```
timeit.timeit('my_array[swap, :] = my_array[swap,:][:,(1,0)]', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

#### Divakar's answer: 0.176 seconds

```
timeit.timeit('np.where(swap[:,None]!=1,my_array,my_array[:,::-1])', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

#### Yatu's first answer: 0.214 seconds

```
timeit.timeit('np.take_along_axis(my_array, np.c_[swap, 1-swap], axis=1)', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

#### Yatu's second answer: 0.2547 seconds

```
timeit.timeit('my_array[swap,:] = my_array[swap,::-1]', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

### Conclusions

Profiling shows Divakar's version is the fastest. Whichever is more intuitive or readable is a matter of flavors, you can pick the one you prefer (I personally am a fan of the indexing notation readability-wise though...)

Comment: @yatu Edited it in ;) I originally didn't put it when I saw it because it's very similar to mine, but then I thought the `::-1` might affect timings in an interesting way. Turns out, it doesn't seem to be significant in the timing differences (reruns have a higher difference than the differences between your 2nd method and my proposal)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using `np.take_along_axis`:

```
np.take_along_axis(my_array, np.c_[swap, 1-swap], axis=1)

array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [5, 4],
       [7, 6],
       [8, 9]])
```

---

Or a boolean indexing based one:

```
swap = swap.astype(bool)
my_array[swap,:] = my_array[swap,::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that swaps for `Nx2` array and flips for more number of columns with the negative stepsize slicing as you were attempting -

```
In [56]: np.where(swap[:,None]==1, my_array[:,::-1], my_array)
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [5, 4],
       [7, 6],
       [8, 9]])
```

Syntax is : `np.where(conditional_statement, choose_for_True, choose_for_False)`. So, in our case, we want to flip/swap when `swap` is `1`, else don't. That `[:,None]` part is needed to do this elementwise across each row. If `swap` is already a boolean array, skip the comparison part.